# How to fix Mixed Content issue

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.yourside.com' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS

I have already checked to update HTTP to HTTPS but not sure from which plugin it is rendering the Javascript file.I have checked all the files for reference but not found any file with this Javascript.

Need help guys.

Comment: plugin ?  what framework or else do you use?

Comment: @ob_start I am using wordpress with divi theme.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your sharethis url from this

```
http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js
```

to this

```
https://ws.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js
```

You can read more about it here http://support.sharethis.com/customer/portal/articles/475097-ssl-support#sthash.VsVVawLB.dpbs

Comment: I haven’t found reference for this link in my whole project.